# Symbology templates mess up colors and legend labels when used in Python script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, symbology, layer-file

I'm having issues when trying to symbolize a layer from a .lyr template using a python script. The templates work when imported in ArcMap as seen below:

[image]

[image]

But when run with the following Python code:

```
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "dfImage" + str(dfNum))[0]
    legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "LEGEND_ELEMENT", "dfImage" + str(dfNum) +"_legend")[0]
    fc1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fcGrid)
    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, fc1, arcpy.mapping.Layer(symbologyTemplatePath + "VI_data.lyr"))
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(fc1, arcpy.mapping.Layer(symbologyTemplatePath + "VI_data.lyr"))
    fc1.symbology.valueField = gridCol
    legend.autoAdd = True
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, fc1, "BOTTOM")
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    for lyr in legend.listLegendItemLayers():
        legend.updateItem(lyr, styleItem)
    legend.elementHeight = 1.0
```

It changes the colors, and the legend labels aren't truncated to 2 decimal places:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I apply lyr symbology, but the legend will not update in the python code. I have tried similar things to you. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: This should be a comment not a answer